# HTML 5 Elements, non-JS fallbacks

Tags: html, seo, fallback

Let me start with my "restrictions" in my web-dev situation.
1.) Site must work in IE7.
2.) Site must work for non-js browsers.

My situation is very SEO heavy. Google rankings are everything in this situation.
HTML 5 added tags such as article, header, footer, etc., and it is my understanding that these tags can improve SEO.
That being said, my two restrictions make implementation of these tags a bit more difficult, if not impossible. I'm aware of shim options, however, for users not using JS, these options aren't possible, as they aren't a real solution.
An idea popped into my head, and I'd just like some feedback on if it would be possible. See the code below:
HTML:

```
<header><div class="header">Header content</div></header>
```

CSS:

```
header, .header { identical properties }
```

Would this be a possible solution?
If so, would it be wise to put the header tag first, or the div tag first in the markup? My initial thought was the HTML 5 element, as to be sure this is scanned by search engines.

Comment: Did any of the solutions help? Please select an answer if possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no evidence of SEO effects of markup like `article`, `header`, `footer`, etc. There is a lot of speculation about them.

Using redundant markup like you describe would be harmless, but it would not produce any tangible gain as compared with simple `div` elements (which in turn are needed only for styling or scripting, if at all). The order of nesting does not matter, but since the new elements would be basically for documentation purposes, it would be more natural to use them as outer elements and `div` as inner.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to include the header tag, then that looks like a good solution.

The only advice I can add is to make sure that the "identical properties" for your header tag and .header class don't contain attributes like padding or margins because these attributes may be applied to both the header and .header in browsers that support HTML5 (effectively doubling the padding or margins).

Also, META tags can be useful for SEO, so don't forget about those too!